# Converting Starting and Ending Time Differences into num

Tags: excel

Was unable to find an answer when I searched for a solution, even though this may be a very simple solution.

We have a log that captures a start time and end time.  I'm trying to capture the difference between the two times in minutes.  When I export the data into Excel it looks like this:

```
(Col A)-start_time| (Col B)-end_time
----------------- | ----------------
0:12              | 0:48
0:37              | 1:30
0:22              | 0:38
0:54              | 1:12
```

It defaults as a Custom Format of:  h:mm

Here are the actual cell values

```
            (Col A)             (Col B)
            start_time          end_time
(Row 1)     12:12:00 AM         12:48:00 AM
(Row 2)     12:37:00 AM          1:30:00 AM
(Row 3)     12:22:00 AM         12:38:00 AM
(Row 4)     12:54:00 AM          1:12:00 AM
```

When I subtract end_time from start_time for these times I get:

```
            (Col A)             (Col B)        (Col C)
            start_time          end_time       time_variance
(Row 1)     0:12                0:48           0:36
(Row 2)     0:37                1:30           0:53
(Row 3)     0:22                0:38           0:16
(Row 4)     0:54                1:12           0:18
```

What I would like to be able to do is to have the difference expressed as a number.  So, if Rows: 1-2 were the "party" category and Rows: 3-4 were the "sleep" category the sum would give me 89 minutes for party and 34 minutes for sleep.

When I view the values for the difference I get results I don't understand.  The "36" minutes from row 1 col 1 is 0.025.  Would someone explain how I can convert the value of 36 minutes displayed as a time to a numeric value of 36 or point me to an existing solution?  Thank you.

Comment: Excel stores dates/times as days + fractions of a day.  So 36 minutes divided by the number of minutes in a day = .025.  or 0.025*24*60 = 36.  OR, you can just subtract the two cells in time format and you'll get the result in time format.

Comment: Ron, Thank you for the solution.  I appreciate the help.